# x.lower() makes my string uniterable. why

Tags: python, lowercase

I created a code in python to search a word in document . The documents are stored as dictionary with a 'url' as their key and the content as the value. I wanted to convert the text of the document to lowercase before performing search operation.

```
def get_page(url):
    if url in cache:
        x=cache[url]
        return x.lower()
    else:
        return None
```

I used this code. `cache` is the dictionary, `url` is the key.
But I get this error...

```
Line 324: TypeError: Cannot call method 'tp$iter' of null
```

which I assumed was for an uniterable string.

Error occurs here, in the first line

```
for char in source:
    if char in splitlist:
        atsplit = True
```

`source` is same as `x` from the function quoted above.

Comment: That sounds like JavaScript, not Python. Are you running it on some kind of Python->JavaScript converter? Anyway, `None` isn’t iterable.

Comment: Presumably, that happens when you have a cache miss, and `get_page` returns `None`.

Comment: strings are always iterable, never heard of `uniterable` strings.

Comment: Change the `return None` to `return ""`.

Comment: the code was working fine. but then i added that x.lower function in the return statement.
Does it make any change which may have caused this error

Comment: What kind of error is that? null? I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: @user1928482 Python doesn't use `null`. What are you running this in?

Comment: @minitech i'm using **codeskulptor.org**

Comment: It would help if you would show more code. What's populating `cache`?

Comment: @martineau thank you. that seems to have solved the problem
can u tell me what actually was the issue

Comment: @user1928482: Sure, see my answer which also has some other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't run into the loop `for char in source` when you return `None` because `None` is not iterable. Instead of returning None, you could also return `""`, depends on how you're using the `get_page` function

Simple demo that you assumption is not true

```
for char in "google.com".lower():
    print(char)


# python test.py
g
o
o
g
l
e
.
c
o
m
```

Answer (score 0):

That almost certainly means that the `else:` clause in your `get_page()` function is getting hit. It's not that you have an uniterable string; it's that you've got `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is the miss hit case when you check your cache. Here is the updated function with examples cases.

```
cache = {}
x = ""

def get_page(url):
    if url in cache:
        x=cache[url]
        return x.lower()
    else:
        return ""

url = 'some KEY'
cache[url] = 'some VALUE'

print get_page(url)
x = get_page(url)

for char in x:
    print 'It works now'



print get_page('Does not exist')
x = get_page('Does not exist')

for char in x:
    print 'It works now'
```

Comment: without that lower function , the code was working for the same input
how does adding that lower function modify the control so as to hit the 'else' clause

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when your function returns `None`, which isn't iterable. 
A simple fix would be:

```
def get_page(url):
    if url in cache:
        x=cache[url]
        return x.lower()
    else:
        return ""
```

This works because a string, even an empty one, *is* iterable (zero times), so returning an empty one as a result avoids the `TypeError` when the `url` isn't in the `cache`.

You could simplify your function to one line by using the `cache` dictionary's `get()` method which will return a default value when the item isn't found. Again, this works because it's also possible to lowercase empty strings, so you can avoid having to special case the `url` not being found.

```
def get_page(url):
    return cache.get(url, "").lower()
```